# How do you create a specialized iOS bookshelf app?

Tags: ios

I am working on a project for a client who does not want to publish their multimedia books to the iBooks store or the Newsstand app. They want an app that resembles the iBooks bookshelf with individual books displayed on the shelf. They also want the individual books to show up as apps in the app store and end up in the company branded bookshelf app. Similar to the Cat In the Hat series.

Are there any guidelines on how this can be done? InApp linking?

Here is how the cat in the hat app works.

You download the Dr.Suess bookshelf app. Upon launching the app, it displays a customized list of other books you can purchase. When you tap on a book, it launches the app store on the device and you complete the purchase via the device's app store. This will download the new book as an additional app on your device. If you relaunch the "bookshelf" app the newly downloaded book (app) is listed on the "My Books" shelf.

Essentially the bookshelf app acts as a container for other books which are downloaded onto the device and do appear as separate apps.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am not looking for UICollectionView or Grid Solutions. The core of the problem is how can individual books be deployed as apps but yet be contained within another app that looks like a bookshelf.

Comment: Which Cat in the Hat books do you mean? Possibly because I'm in the UK I'm not seeing them.

Comment: Cat In the Hat has an app that when downloaded, resembles a bookshelf. Additional books are listed as apps on the App Store but when you download them, they will appear in the container app. To open a book, you will open the container app and tap on a book on the shelf. It's as if the container is a pointer to a bunch of interactive book apps installed on the phone but each of those books do not litter your phone.

Comment: Rather than re-posting substantially the same question next time, just flag for us to migrate things like I have done here so that the answerer from the first site can participate once the question ends up on the proper site.

Comment: @rams Would you provide links to the Cat in the Hat and its additional books in the App Store so we can see what's going on? I've never seen an app with the behaviour you're describing (apps on the App Store that are actually components of another app). Are you sure The Cat in the Hat isn't using *in-app purchase* to add books?

Comment: @Dan, this is where I am looking for some guidance. I am trying to wrap my head around how a container app can wrap other "apps" on its bookshelf. So far my googling has not resulted in any good leads.

However, of I use In-App purchase to add new books, would that app be restricted to the2GB limit? At some point, say after downloading 2 books, I would have to remove a few to download new issues?

Answer (score 3):

You will be in two Apple violations if you create this App:

A.) Apple is not allowing the App with simple book with PDF reader sort of functionality.

They are forcing users to choose iBooks options.

Rejection: We received rejection when uploading two apps both are eBooks. 
We have worked on 3 Months (Powering 100+ Travelogue and Apps)for creating kickass PDF / Magazine reader and we got rejection. Because App has only PDF reader.

Possible solution: Your PDF reader should provide a functionality which iBooks app don't provide may be some Video or interactive content inside your book.

We ended up including interactive content along with book and some other Contact us form and stuff that approved on App Store.

B.) Same Application - Different Name

This will certainly reject your app.

Rejection: We created City Guide framework with really good design and started uploading different city guides with same design and different content. 
Our apps got rejected with same design with different content.

Possible resolution: Don't do this approach. Either have in-app purchase for enabling the book purchase or invest on App Store optimization.

You can find the bookshelf for iOS component as Open Source on GitHub

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The books in question are interactive books with ability to highlight words to have them pronounced, multiple languages etc.

The question I have is, is it possible to release each of the multi-media books as apps listed on the app store yet when downloaded, show up in the special branded bookshelf app.

Comment: @rams Be sure to edit your question to narrow down your question if possible. Specific questions about the app review may or may not be covered with an NDA, but at least we'll all know exactly what information you lack or what you don't get about publishing content through an iTunes Connect account.

Comment: @bmike I have copied the question over to Stackoverflow and am getting a few responses.

Comment: Hi, i am also having the same problem ? So for creating such interactive PDF file what are the tools/framework you have used ? Also for reading it back inside app what are the framework you have used ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty broad reaching question, but if the client is happy with iOS6 only there's `UICollectionView` which allows you to have a grid of items in a specific layout, then you're handling drawing the background images to simulate the bookshelf style.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify I am looking for guidance on how to create the container app that will allow for multiple books to be downloaded when the books themselves show up as individual apps in the AppStore. For example, when searched, Book1, Books2, Book3, etc will display as individual apps but when downloaded will be showcased with in the "special bookshelf" app.

Answer (score 2):

I utilised [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) to produce a bookshelf-type layout for my document viewing app.

I customised [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-small-business-app-project-setup/) from the Mobile Tuts site and ended with a layout like this:

[image]

You should be able to get something similar with `UICollectionView` but I haven't tested that.